# Problem with tkzLabelX in tkz-euclide : not found

Tags: tkz-euclide

Trying to compile my own tex file (which worked before), the tkzLabelX is not found anymore. So, I tried in the following simple example.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmax=6,xmin=1,xstep=1]   
\tkzDrawX[label=$t$,text=blue,noticks=false,color=red]
\tkzLabelX[text=blue,below = 3pt]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this example, the tkzLabelX command is not found either.

Does anyone have any lead ?

I specify that:

- My packages are all updated (Last version 2023).
- I checked the previous questions on the subject. I found : "Problem with label and tick in tkz-euclide" Asked 2 years, Modified 2 years and 5 months ago. Besides, the example given above comes from SebGlav in this post.
- In /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide, I grep "LabelX" in all the files with the command line :

```
grep LabelX *.tex
```

It appears that there is no LabelX occurence.

Comment: In the current version, you need to add the line `\usepackage{tkz-base}` before `\usepackage{tkz-euclide}`.  Then it will work.  Although, unless you are going to use the macros from `tkz-euclide`, you don't need to load it. Your example will work with just `tkz-base`.

Answer (score 0):

(Welcome to Tex.SE -- great first question).

Sometime in a recent version change, `tkz-euclide` was cleaned up and certain macros moved to the [`tkz-base`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-base?lang=en) package.

The Cartesian coordinate system appears to be one of these.  So to make your example work you need to change from `tkz-euclide` to `tkz-base`.  Like so:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmax=6,xmin=1,xstep=1]   
\tkzDrawX[label=$t$,text=blue,noticks=false,color=red]
\tkzLabelX[text=blue,below=3pt]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

when I compile that, I get a PDF that looks like this:

[image]

which I think is what you wanted.

Note that if you also want some of the macros from `tkz-euclide`, then you should add `\usepackage{tkz-euclide}` **after** the `\usepackage{tkz-base}` line.

Comment: It perfectly works now ! My sincerest thanks for your answer.